# I have an image I would like to use to control an <audio> source. I can't find a way to use both the pause and play function simultaneously

Tags: html, onclick, html5-audio

So, I have an audio track autoplay when opening the website

```
<audio class="topper" autoplay loop id="minuscolo">
    <source src="media/minuscolo.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

and I have an image that I would like to use to control the music

```
<img class="hvr-shrink square" alt="Pause" src="media/gogh.png" onclick="document.getElementById('minuscolo').pause()">
```

I can assign a play or pause function to it, but I can't find a way to use both functions on the same image so that if music is playing it acts as a pause button and if there's no music playing it acts as a play button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve what you want by reading the `paused` property. It will return `true` if the audio is paused, or `false` if it's not. Then apply the `.play()` or `.pause()` methods accordingly.

To do this, just use a simple `if ... else` structure (pseudocode):

```
if (audio.paused) { audio.play() } else { audio.pause() }
```

Or to make it shorter you could use the conditional ternary operator (`? :`) like this (pseudocode):

```
audio.paused ? audio.play() : audio.pause()
```

That applied to your code would look like this (changed the image and audio for the demo):

```html
<audio class="topper" autoplay loop id="minuscolo">
    <source src="http://www.html5tutorial.info/media/vincent.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

<img class="hvr-shrink square" alt="Pause" src="http://lorempixel.com/g/100/100/abstract/" onclick="document.getElementById('minuscolo').paused ? document.getElementById('minuscolo').play() : document.getElementById('minuscolo').pause()">
```

You can also see it on this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k1qkko1q/).

Having everything online is a bit *ugly*. It would be nicer if you attached a `click` event on the element that called a function, and then have the JavaScript logic separated from the HTML code. [Like it is explained on this W3C wiki link](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/audio).